# How to use an image for a border in CSS

Tags: css, image, border

I want to set the border of a table to be "1px solid black" except on the bottom, where I want to use an image which provides a pointer into the link - as a visual aid.

Is it possible to set an image as the bottom border when the other borders are regular css.

Answer (score 14):

Try putting the table inside `<div class="myTableContainer"></div>` and then:

```
.myTableContainer{
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  background: url(myBorderImage.png) bottom left;
}
```

This should work well across all browsers.

Answer (score 5):

CSS3 has added support for border-image. You can find more information at http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-images. At this point (early 2012), it's probably not safe to use due to lack of support in all versions of IE. To track when it is safe to use you can visit http://caniuse.com/#search=border-image. One way to simulate the border-image style is to use a positioned background-image. For example, to simulate a top border:

```
div
{
  background-image: url('topBorder.gif');
  background-position: top;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. You're probably better off adding a <DIV> below the table, give it a black border, a fixed background, and some fixed padding or whatnot (to give it some size).

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to style your element with a background image in css and then specify an offset for the background in CSS. The background can poke out from beyond the edge of the element (a div or li element for example). This can be used for many different effects, one being the appearance of a drop shadow using pure css.

Some specifics here:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/cssdropshadows/

Answer (score 2):

Now there is **CSS3** and a `border-image` property for that, but still it does not work for all browsers.

OK, let's there be a [W3Schools link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp) on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

No. Why don't you try another table row for that purpose?

Comment: Using tables for layout purposes, eh? Tsk, tsk, tsk. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a  below your table then set his style like

```
.bottomborder {
  height:1px;
  background-image:url("yourImage.png");
}
```

Should work good.

Edit : and of course border-top, left, right for your table a "solid 1px black"

Answer (score 0):

You can set the borders like that except the bottom border :

```
border-top:1px solid black;
border-right:1px solid black;
border-left:1px solid black;
```

For the bottom border, you can set your image as background of a row maybe.